# How to decompose data in R

Tags: r, decomposition

Does anyone have suggestions on how to decompose this data set in r? Also, the first column is coming up as character, but when I ran ggplot, it was correctly analyzed as date data. Do I still need to convert it to date? And if so, how?

[image: please click here for data set]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What do you mean by decomposition?

Comment: I would like to get graphs of seasonal, trend, random and observed data.

Comment: Please read and edit your question according to: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Can you add example of your data using `dput()` function? Also, explain wanted output. How this random data should be generated? You can also add your `ggplot2` function.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16vjT4l-2Krnu8gpjpa7BP83ayjw1AChZ/view?usp=sharing <Here is the full data list. I first want to convert this to a time series, which I tried to do with:  ts(data, frequency=12, start=c(2004,01), end=c(2017,12)) but I am getting an error that says "In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion". I'm thinking this is the first hurdle to get over before talking about decomposition.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the source of the data?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am trying to fight my way back from my own imagination, away from the dark vision of decomposed composers... However, if *season* means *year*, and *decomposition* means *summary* of the composer's popularity over the year, using [your data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16vjT4l-2Krnu8gpjpa7BP83ayjw1AChZ/view), it might be done this way:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggthemes)

read_csv("test2.csv") %>%     
  mutate(date = ymd(paste(month,"-01", sep="")), month = NULL) %>%
  mutate(season = cut(date, "year")) %>% 
  group_by(season, composer) %>%
  summarise(popularity = mean(popularity)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year(season), y = popularity, group = composer, colour = composer)) +
      geom_line(alpha = 0.75) +
      ggthemes::scale_colour_gdocs(name = "Composer:") + # comment out this line
      labs(x = "Season", y = "Popularity") +
      ggthemes::theme_few()                              # comment out this line
```

[image: trendy composers]

Comment: This helps a lot! Thank you- I didn't think about finding the mean of popularity.

Comment: I'm glad to help.